# Stacking multidimensional numpy arrays with one different dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, neural-network

Alright - assume I have two numpy arrays, shapes are:

```
(185, 100, 50, 3)

(64,  100, 50, 3)
```

The values contained are 185 or 64 frames of video (for each frame, width is 100 pixels, height is 50, 3 channels, these are just images. The specifics of the images remain constant - the only value that changes is the number of frames per video)
I need to get them both into a single array of some shape like

```
(2, n, 100, 50, 3)
```

Where both videos are contained (to run through a neural net as a batch)

I've already tried using np.stack - but I get

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Comment: So, what must be `n` then?

Comment: Why not an array of shape (185+64, 100, 50, 3)? What is the task you want het NN to learn and how to these two video's relate to that task?

Comment: @Divakar In the dimensions of my network - i can assign "none" and it will allow for ambiguous length. Is there anything similar for numpy, or will i have to make the arrays (2,185,100,50,3) and just pad the (64,100,50,3) with zeros...?

Comment: Start with a smaller sample `(5,3)` and `(4,3)` with numerical values  and then, you might expect a `(2,n,3)` shaped array. So, what must be the expected output?

Comment: make the smaller array the same size as the larger by *filling with zeroes* then concatenate/stack/whatever.

Comment: @agtoever They're separate videos (i'm doing video to caption stuff) - and the output array is two separate captions... Putting them into one single array wouldn't work. I'm just trying to get an array that I can feed into the network as a batch.

Comment: @wwii it's looking more and more like that's what i'll have to do - networks learn to ignore padding anyways, so it should be fine.

Comment: What are the constraints on your output? Would it be possible to simply put the two arrays in a list and output that?

Comment: @jmcampbell they need to be in a single numpy array with a first dimension of 2 (the batch size) to 'fit' into the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick brainstorm idea that I've got, along with strategy and Python code. Note: I was going to stick to just comment but to illustrate this idea I'd need to type in some codes. So here we go! (grab a coffee / a strong drink is recommended...)

## Current State

- we have video 1 `vid1` with 4D shape `(185, 100, 50, 3)`
- we have video 2 `vid2` with 4D shape `(64, 100, 50, 3)`
- ... where the shape represents `(frame ID, width, height, RGB channels)`
- we want to "stack" the two videos together as one numpy array with 5D shape `(2, n, 100, 50, 3)`. Note: `2` because we are stacking 2 videos. `n` is a hyperparameter that we can choose. We keep the video size the same (`100 width x 50 height x 3 RGB channels`)

## Opportunities

The first thing I see is that `vid1` has roughly 3 times more frames than `vid2`. What about we use `60` as the common factor? i.e. let's set our hyperparameter `n` to `60`. (Note: some "frame cropping" / "frame throwing away" may be required - this will be covered below.)

## Strategy

#### Phase 1 - Crop both videos (throw away some frames)

Let's crop both `vid1` and `vid2` to nice round numbers that are of multiple of `60` (our `n` - the hyperparameter). Concretely:

- crop `vid1` so that the shape becomes `(180, 100, 50, 3)`. (i.e. we throw away the last 5 frames). We call this new cropped video `vid1_cropped`.
- crop `vid2` so that the shape becomes `(60, 100, 50, 3)`. (i.e. we throw away the last 4 frames). We call this new cropped video `vid2_cropped`.

#### Phase 2 - Make both videos 60 frames

- `vid2_cropped` is already at 60 frames, with shape `(60, 100, 50, 3)`. So we leave this alone.
- `vid1_cropped` however is at 180 frames. So I suggest we reduce this video to 60 frames, by averaging the RGB channel values in 3-frame batches - for all pixel positions (along width and height). What we will get at the end of this process, is a somewhat "diluted" (averaged) video with the same shape as `vid2_cropped` - `(60, 100, 50, 3)`. Let's called this diluted video `vid1_cropped_diluted`.

#### Phase 3 - stack the two same-shape videos together

Now that both `vid2_cropped` and `vid1_cropped_diluted` are of the same 4D shape `(60, 100, 50, 3)`. We may stack them together to obtain our final numpy array of 5D shape `(2, 60, 100, 50, 3)` - let's call this `vids_combined`.

We are done!

## Demo

Turning the strategy into codes. I did this in Python 3.6 (with Jupyter Notebook / Jupyter Console).

---

Some notes:

- I yet to validate the code (and revised as needed). In the meantime If you see any bugs please shout - I will be happy to update.
- I have a gut feeling line 10 below on "diluting" (np.average step) might contain error. i.e. I mean to perform the 3-frame averaging only against the RGB channel values, for all pixel positions. I need to double check syntax. (In the meantime please kindly check line 10!)
- this post illustrates concepts and some code implementation. Ideally I would have step through this in more depth, via much smaller video sizes so we may obtain better intuition / visualise each step, pixel by pixel. (I might come back to this when I have time). For now, I believe the numpy array shape analysis is sufficient to convey the idea across.

---

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: vid1 = np.random.random((185, 100, 50, 3))

In [3]: vid1.shape
Out[3]: (185, 100, 50, 3)

In [4]: vid2 = np.random.random((64, 100, 50, 3))

In [5]: vid2.shape
Out[5]: (64, 100, 50, 3)

In [6]: vid1_cropped = vid1[:180]

In [7]: vid1_cropped.shape
Out[7]: (180, 100, 50, 3)

In [8]: vid2_cropped = vid2[:60]

In [9]: vid2_cropped.shape
Out[9]: (60, 100, 50, 3)

In [10]: vid1_cropped_diluted = np.average(vid1_cropped.reshape(3,60,100,50,3),
       : axis=0)

In [11]: vid1_cropped_diluted.shape
Out[11]: (60, 100, 50, 3)

In [12]: vids_combined = np.stack([vid1_cropped_diluted, vid2_cropped])

In [13]: vids_combined.shape
Out[13]: (2, 60, 100, 50, 3)
```

Comment: wow - thanks so much for such a detailed response. Currently I'm padding the data with zeroes to make the smaller video the same length as the larger one, but I'll mess around and see if I can write a solution using the ideas from this answer.

Comment: You are more than welcome Robbie - I have a feeling I will bump into similar challenge soon and it's great to see you've got there first! Do keep us posted how things go and Good luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't stack arrays with different dimensions, since you need a value for each dimension.

Your options are therefore to:

1. not use arrays at all, and simply use a python list
2. pad the arrays with zeros until they are the same shape
3. resample the arrays to the same shape

Atlas7's answer is an implementation of 3, but you'd probably do better to use `scipy.ndimage.zoom` in some way, for a more flexible solution